# Deploying my Node.js app to Digital ocean

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy my Node.js app to a Digital Ocean Droplet, and I've been following this guide to try and set it up https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/deploy-your-nodejs-application-to-a-digital-ocean-droplet-step-by-step-guide-3f6f928f776.

However when I'm running the ssh root @ ipadress in my terminal I'm getting the following error:
ssh: Could not resolve hostname root: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what the issue might be?

Tried rooting @droplet ipadress

Answer (score 0):

As said before, there is PuTTY or a number of others like it:
Solar-PuTTY.
Bitvise SSH Client.
KiTTY.
SuperPuTTY.
PuTTYTray.
mRemoteNG.
MobaXterm.
Xshell.
What you can install is the original does not fit. Then it's up to you to choose.

Comment: You have any recommendation for mac? :-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).